# Shopify Website is giving white space on right side in Ipad Only

Tags: ios, css, ipad, shopify, responsive

I'm facing an issue on this website [fearofmissingoutfomo.com](https://fearofmissingoutfomo.com/) where there is a white bar on the right side when viewing in iPad.
my code is

```
html,body { 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
border: 0;
@include smooth_font();}
{% if settings.use_bg_image %}
body {
background: {{settings.shop_bg_color}} url({{ 'bg.png' | asset_url }}) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
body.index-template {
 background: {{settings.shop_bg_color}} url({{ 'bg.png' | asset_url }}) 0 0 no-repeat;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Help will be really appreciated. I also see some related threads but can't relate that to my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happenning because of this section:
[image]

Currently you section has HTML like that

```
<div id="shopify-section-1509186783462" class="shopify-section  index-section products-grid">
   <section data-section-id="1509186783462" data-section-type="products">
      <div class="section-header text-center">
         <h2>View our featured christmas items</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="grid grid--uniform grid--view-items">
         ......
      </div>
      <div class="text-center view-more btn">
         <a href="/collections/christmas">
         See more
         </a>
      </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

You should fix it and add `container` and `row` like that:

```
<div id="shopify-section-1509186783462" class="shopify-section  index-section products-grid">
   <section data-section-id="1509186783462" data-section-type="products">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="section-header text-center">
               <h2>View our featured christmas items</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid--uniform grid--view-items">
               ......
            </div>
            <div class="text-center view-more btn">
               <a href="/collections/christmas">
               See more
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot Victor you saved my life Thanks :-) i marked answer corrected :-)